# Движение объекта по svg path при скролле

Tags: jquery, svg

Есть такой код:

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    initContainer();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    setMotionPath();
});

function initContainer() {
    var element = $('.svg');
    var motionPath = MorphSVGPlugin.pathDataToBezier("#way").reverse();
    TweenLite.set("#circle", { transformOrigin: "50% 50%" });    

    setMotionPath();    
};

function setMotionPath() {
    var element = $('.svg');
    var motionPath = MorphSVGPlugin.pathDataToBezier("#way").reverse();

     TweenLite.to("#circle", 0, {
            x: motionPath["x"],
            y: motionPath["y"]
        });
};
```

```css
#circle {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>



<svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="way" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="4,2" stroke-width="1" d="M 100,10 L 100,30 L 100,50 L 100,70 L 100,90 L 100,110 L 100,130 L 100,150 L 100,170 L 100,190 L 100,210 L 100,230 L 100,250 L 100,270 L 100,290 L 100,310"></path>

  <circle cx="100" cy="30" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="orange" id="circle"/>
</svg>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/vpGpdw)

**Вопрос:** Как можно застваить круг двигаться по пути `path` плавно при скролле (желательно с использованием TweenMax)?

**P.S:** Путь `path` может быть какой угодно, прямая выбрана для примера, а так он может быть и такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <path id="pPath"
         d="m782.19032,61.21567c-5.10542,4.08434 -38.80117,92.91857 -108.23481,123.55105c-69.43365,30.63249 -187.87928,-10.21082 -178.68954,-76.58122c9.18974,-66.37041 135.80405,-60.24388 138.86731,8.16868c3.06326,68.41254 -36.759,102.1083 -107.21373,120.48779c-70.45474,18.37948 -128.9788,10.90961 -163.64275,0.48347c-34.66395,-10.42613 -110.54388,-54.17155 -159.01952,-99.52852"
          stroke-dasharray="5 2"
          stroke-width="2"
          stroke="#000"
          fill="transparent"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как видно ответ был идеально по той библиотеке которой вы хотели.

Comment: @StackOverflow, и Вам спасибо! Видела и лучше, но разобраться с чужим кодом не могу

Comment: Интересно можете скинуть этот код? хочу посмотреть

Comment: Ну да но там криво работает, Движение не плавное.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот обновленный вариант ответа. Это именно то что вы хотели.

Попытаюсь примерно объяснить что и как работает.

`motionPath` - это массив в котором содержится координаты линии, но в нем не по пиксельно есть все координаты. А линия разделяется на куски, и по каждому куску выбирается координат(центр). Когда вы методом `TweenLite.to` задаете одну пару координат то анимация доходит до него и останавливается. Но если попытаться так при скролле каждый раз дать новые координаты то анимация не будет плавной потому что при скролле не закончив первую часть пути круг уже получает новые координаты и идет по ним (выходя из линии).

Есть второй вариант. Даем сразу массив координат в метод `TweenLite.to` и в переменной сохраним идентификатор анимации `tween = TweenLite.to........`.
После этого мы уже можем манипулировать с анимацией (к примеру сделать паузу).
И еще один важным момент, `tween` уже имеет метод `progress()`, и его значение может быть от 0 до единицы. И если мы зададим промежуточный прогресс, то анимация возвратиться к нему.

Вот так и делаем, задаем прогресс при каждом скролле, и с разу же делаем паузу анимации.

Вот и наш ожидаемый результат.

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    initContainer();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    setMotionPath();
});

function initContainer() {
    var element = $('.svg');
    var motionPath = MorphSVGPlugin.pathDataToBezier("#way",{align:"#circle"}).reverse();
    TweenLite.set("#circle", {xPercent:-50, yPercent:-50});  
    setMotionPath();    
};

function setMotionPath() {
    var element = $('.svg');
    var way = $('#way');
    var motionPath = MorphSVGPlugin.pathDataToBezier("#way",{align:"#circle"}).reverse();
    var progress_val = $(window).scrollTop()/5000;
    tween = TweenLite.to("#circle", 3, {bezier:{values:motionPath, type:"cubic"}});
    tween.progress( progress_val ).pause();
};
```

```css
#circle {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 400%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>

<svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 900 900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="way"
         d="m782.19032,61.21567c-5.10542,4.08434 -38.80117,92.91857 -108.23481,123.55105c-69.43365,30.63249 -187.87928,-10.21082 -178.68954,-76.58122c9.18974,-66.37041 135.80405,-60.24388 138.86731,8.16868c3.06326,68.41254 -36.759,102.1083 -107.21373,120.48779c-70.45474,18.37948 -128.9788,10.90961 -163.64275,0.48347c-34.66395,-10.42613 -110.54388,-54.17155 -159.01952,-99.52852"
          stroke-dasharray="5 2"
          stroke-width="2"
          stroke="#000"
          fill="transparent"/>

  <circle cx="100" cy="30" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="orange" id="circle"/>
</svg>
```

Для прямой линии.

Здесь не нужен `reverse` получаемых координат. Этот плагин имеет большое количество опций. Все это уже можете посмотреть сами.

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    initContainer();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    setMotionPath();
});

function initContainer() {
    var element = $('.svg');
    var motionPath = MorphSVGPlugin.pathDataToBezier("#way",{align:"#circle"}).reverse();
    TweenLite.set("#circle", {xPercent:-50, yPercent:-50});  
    setMotionPath();    
};

function setMotionPath() {
    var element = $('.svg');
    var way = $('#way');
    var motionPath = MorphSVGPlugin.pathDataToBezier("#way",{align:"#circle"});
    var progress_val = $(window).scrollTop()/1000;
    tween = TweenLite.to("#circle", 3, {bezier:{values:motionPath, type:"cubic"}});
    tween.progress( progress_val ).pause();
};
```

```css
#circle {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 400%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>

<svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 900 900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="way" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="4,2" stroke-width="1" d="M 100,10 L 100,30 L 100,50 L 100,70 L 100,90 L 100,110 L 100,130 L 100,150 L 100,170 L 100,190 L 100,210 L 100,230 L 100,250 L 100,270 L 100,290 L 100,310"></path>
  <circle cx="100" cy="30" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="orange" id="circle"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @HamSter Да я дополню ответ немного позже, но ваш объект не поможет вам, там всего 4 координата. и если брать их то движение по ним не будет плавной.

Comment: @HamSter Так уже хорошо? Это то что вы хотели.

Comment: @HamSter `progress` как я говорил может быть в диапазоне `0-1`. 0 это начальная точка целой анимации, 1 конечная, если мы даем `tween.progress(0.1545)` то анимация доходит до него. после этого делаем паузу, и ждем следующего события `scroll`. Если дать меньше то `progress_val` быстрее будет равен одному.(ну или больше 1), то есть анимация будет быстрой. А если делить на большую цифру то анимация уже замедлится. Все это можно прикрепить к чему угодно, не только к скроллу.

Comment: @HamSter Прикрепил код и для прямой линии. Линия не важно. Здесь только заданный массив координат важен. по нему определяется начальная и конечная точка анимации.

Comment: спасибо, отличное решение

Comment: @HamSter Не за что, ну тогда зачем галочку что вопрос решен не поставите?

Comment: еще 5 дней, тогда и поставлю если не будет еще ответов, более интересных

Comment: @HamSter В принципе да, но по этому плагину нового не будет, Я там много прочитал дока по нему.))))